# How to move data model automatically?

Tags: gooddata

Can I somehow pull a data model from someone's platform to mine, so I don't need to create the model manually? Is there a chance to make it automatically? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for some cloud datawarehouses GoodData supports “model scan” I believe where you can connect to the database and generate GD LDM based on that. I believe similar mechanism is also in CN. BUT - I would not recommend doing it for production use especially on top of some random database. It might still require some manual tuning to make a reasonable LDM. And from our experience in GD the LDM should be based on the reporting requirements. But for a quick and dirty demo, it might work out of the box.